# Is there any possibility to load video from another alternate URL if the main one failed in video-js player?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have a page contains video with source for multiple videos. Video are hosted on my server. I also have a alternate video server which host the alternate copy of same video. I want to play video from alternate server when it failed to load video from primary automatically.

Here is my sample code:-

```
<video id="videojs-contrib-hls-player" width=760 height=400  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls> <source src="Video1.mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL">
<source src="Video2.mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL">
<source src="Video3.mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Is there any way to specify the alternate video URL which used to play video when primary is failed to load. Or any other way or any event when we can changes the URL of video.